# Not able to get "Git" option in jenkins "Source Code Management" section while creating new item in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am not able to get git option in Source Code Management section while creating new item in jenkins. I have already installed the plugins for it .

1. credentials.hpi
2. git.hpi
3. git-client.hpi
4. github.hpi
5. github-api.hpi
6. mailer.hpi
7. matrix-project.hpi
8. plain-credentials.hpi
9. scm-api.hpi
10. ssh-credentials.hpi
11. token-macro.hpi
12. workflow-scm-step.hpi
13. analysis-core.hpi
14. findbugs.hpi
15. infradna-backup.hpi
16. mapdb-api.hpi
17. parameterized-trigger.hpi
18. subversion.hpi
19. workflow-scm-step.hpi...

Kindly let me know which step i am missing...

Answer (score 0):

The responsible plugin is GIT only

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

Sometimes it requires a Jenkins service restart before the plugin shows in the Jenkins.

Comment: I am not able to restart my Jenkins service and while trying to restart using
(jenkins_url)/safeRestart it is showing "Jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured" I also installed the saferestart.hpi plugin to restart Jenkins but that also didn't work.

Comment: Can you try to restart the service from Jenkins server itself? Check the event logs if it fails to restart.